# How to get Method extensions from gRPC

Tags: go, interceptor, grpc

I am using interceptors to perform additional validation based on the optional extensions set on an RPC on incoming and out going RPCs.
Given the following gRPC schema:

```
extend google.protobuf.MethodOptions {
  string my_option = 50006;
}

service MyService {
  rpc Foo (FooRequest) returns (FooResponse) {
    option (my_option) = "foo"
  }
}
```

How do I go about getting the value of my_option?  At first I had thought to get it from the request using [this](https://github.com/golang/protobuf/issues/179#issuecomment-261146848).  However, as this is a MethodOptions it doesn't seem that its part of the descriptor.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Found the [following answer](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/issues/1526#issuecomment-372481817) for those who get here in the future.